# I can not assign text value to span for Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html

I have a span element that has and id and is empty initially.:

```
<span id="mySpan"></span>
```

In the code-behind I am trying to assign a text value to it like this:

```
$("#mySpan").html("Text for the span");
```

I also tried with `.text` property and it works perfectly on IE and Mozilla but it fails on Chrome.

What could be the reason ?

Comment: is your site online ?

Comment: why do you use | in the end of line?

Comment: My site is not online.

The '|' was just a mistake while typing.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/H5rWN/). You need to provide enough of a test case for the problem to show up.

Comment: Do you have any extensions or plugins installed for Chrome? Try to disable them.

Comment: Can you check if the $("#mySpan") selector is finding the element? 

console.log($("#mySpan").length)

Comment: @Shreyas I have the element in the DOM, but when I select it, and try to get its length, innerHtml or whatever it returns []

Comment: @mathinvalidnik, that suggests that something is wrong.  Can you paste the exact code from your page into the post?  You may have a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [`fiddle here`](http://jsfiddle.net/C3jG2/), which is your code.  Make sure you are **referencing** the Jquery file in your page.  If this fiddle works in chrome, then the issue will be with something else on the page.